# Tutorial on displaying datasets from a SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I am a beginner.

I am connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database.

I would like to display data from a table.

How do I do this? Can someone please show me an easy tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get started is with [LINQ To SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).

Use [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs) to set up LINQ To SQL for your database. You only need to follow the **Create LINQ to SQL Classes** section.

Then, you access the data like this:

```
using (var db = new MyDbDataContext())
{
    var myRecord= db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(myRecord.MyColumn.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thank you. how can i bind one of the the controls to the dataset?

Comment: MyDbDataContext the compiler is not recognizing this word

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DbDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WpfApplication1\Window1.xaml.cs 29 33 WpfApplication1

Comment: Umm, `MyDB` is example text, as is all other code starting with "My". You'll need to replace `MyDB` with whatever you named your model, etc.

Comment: what is the default? DataClasses1?